# Manipulação de Txt - Separar blocos com base em um padrão

Tags: python, txt

Eu possuo um txt com algumas informações. O txt segue o seguinte padrão:

1 - Inicio do bloco

2 - Informação

3 - Descrição da linha 2

Então, por exemplo

```
190845 3890580235203895 0329045832854880328 58908349058340534859 hjdfhgjdfhg dgfdgdf  
22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN
22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN
22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN
120845 3890580235203895 0329045832854880328 58908349058340534859 hjdfhgjdfhg dgfdgdf  
22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN
```

O que eu preciso é separar em varáveis diferentes os blocos sabendo que eles iniciam em 1 e terminam na próxima incidência de 1. O exemplo acima ficaria:

```
a = '190845 3890580235203895 0329045832854880328 58908349058340534859 hjdfhgjdfhg dgfdgdf  
22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN
22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN
22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN'

b = '120845 3890580235203895 0329045832854880328 58908349058340534859 hjdfhgjdfhg dgfdgdf  
22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN'
```

Tentei fazer combinando `while` + `readline` + `startswith`, mas não consegui

Comment: Pode aparecer o valor 1 em qualquer lugar da linha, dentro da informação, ou sempre o 1 representará início do bloco?

Comment: Olá Anderson! Quanto tempo ! Então, o 1 pode aparecer em qualquer lugar do arquivo, mas o 1 que representa o inicio do bloco sempre será na posição 1 da linha

Comment: eu havia tentado o line.startswith("1"), mas para manipular o bloco inteiro ficou inviável

Comment: [Assim](https://repl.it/HmUX) que você fez? Acho que com expressão regular consegue fazer uma solução melhor, mas não consigo pensar em nada neste momento.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tua dica ajudou muito !!

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue utilizar a seguinte expressão regular:

`^1` - Onde o `^` indica o inicio de uma linha seguido do caracter que você esta buscando no caso o `1`. Fiz um exemplo que faço o split do texto utilizando expressao regular e após isto volto concatenando cada item com o 1.

Para montar a expressão regular gosto de utilizar o [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Sx8PL2qdR8)

Codigo: [repl](https://repl.it/HmUX/1)

```
import sys
import re

FINDER = "1"
# [(^1)]
# http://rubular.com/r/Sx8PL2qdR8
REGEX = '[(^' + FINDER + ')]'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    content = """190845 3890580235203895 0329045832854880328 58908349058340534859 hjdfhgjdfhg dgfdgdf  
    22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
    3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN
    22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
    3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN
    22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
    3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN
    120845 3890580235203895 0329045832854880328 58908349058340534859 hjdfhgjdfhg dgfdgdf  
    22343 34234234 324234 324234234 234234 342324989856475959596    
    3SHDSHFUHDSFUHSDUFHSHDFUDSFDSTTJKKHGHJMNMNBN"""

    splitted = re.split(REGEX, content)

    #Verifica e faz a remoção do primeiro item se for vazio
    if splitted[0] == '':
        splitted = splitted[1:]

    #Recupera todos os item juntando com o caracter inicial
    result = []
    for split in splitted:
        result.append(FINDER + split)

    #Exibe o resultado
    print(len(result))
    for r in result:
        print("----> " + r)
```